# Different instances of .Settings class

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a console application that restarts itself via a Powershell script. In a .Settings class I have a stringcollection which stores an array of strings. The application is meant to restart itself and use the values stored in the stringcollection to continue. The problem is when the application restarts itself the stringcollection is empty, if I were to close the application then start the application again via Visual Studio the stringcollection contains the expected values.

E.G.

Visual Studio starts console app - > App executes Powershell script -> Powershell script starts the console app -> Console app .Settings file does not contain expected values -> If I start the app via Visual Studio the .Settings file contains the expected values.

Side note: I am using .Settings.Default.Save().

Any ideas why this happens and how to resolve?

Resolution: .Settings.Default.Upgrade() - Upgrades the session which allows the same instance of the .Settings class to be accessed.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug > untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.  With it enabled you'll save the settings to a different file, one that's based on the projectname.vshost.exe executable name.  Which PowerShell did not start.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for taking the time to comment. I figured out the problem and I will update the op.